# Google+ style autocomplete + dropdown jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, google-plus

I am looking for a jQuery plugin that behaves like the Google+ autocomplete + dropdown. In G+, I can enter a person's name and it'll look in my circles and show me a list of matches, or I can click the dropdown arrow at the end of the input box to get a list of all possible names that I can select from. I was able to find plugins that do the autocomplete, but nothing that mixes that with a dropdown functionality to show you all possible names. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also try the chosen component.
http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/
It's a very nice piece of UI

Answer (score 0):

Try jQueryUI Autocomplete: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: this is exactly what you are looking for; http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox